# Function didParseCell is called twice

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I've paid attention that function in `didParseCell` hook is called twice. Why is it happening and how can I prevent it?

For example, I've checkedit also for this simple table:

```
let doc = new jsPDF()
doc.autoTable({
  body: [[1]], 
  didParseCell: data => {
    console.log(data.cell.text)
  }
})
doc.save('table.pdf')
```

Function in didParseCell is called for all cells and then called again for all cells. Why does it happen?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: I've edited the post. Thank you!

Comment: I simplified the example further. It seems like there is a bug with the library. Maybe you can post an issue on github?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure how to do it...